# javascript, combining AND, OR in an if starement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I would like my code to be able to do the following:

`IF` (value1 is less than -1 `AND` variable2 does not equal either 6 or 5) then...

So far I could get a single `if and` to work as follows;

```
if ( (value < -1 && (day !== 6)) )  sendEmail(value)
```

but as soon as I add in the second or it falls over. What am I doing wrong? I have tried it in a few different ways but below are a couple of examples that did not work.

```
if ( (value < -1 && (day !== 6 || 5)) )  sendEmail(value)

if ( (value < -1 && (day !== 6 || day !== 5)) )  sendEmail(value)
```

Comment: The last line of code is closest, but think about the logic: if `day` is 6, then it's not equal to 5; if it's 5, then it's not equal to 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your logic. Basically what you want is:

```
IF (value1 is less than -1 AND variable2 is not equal to 6 AND variable2 is not equal to 5)
```

Therefore your if statement can be written as:

```
if (value < -1 && day != 6 && day != 5) sendEmail(value);
```

Comment: @AdamLambert, if this answer helped you, please do me a favor and accept it by clicking on the checkmark under the upvote count. That will mark this question as answered and will give both you and me some SO Rep.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(value < -1 && day !== 6 && day !== 5)  sendEmail(value)
```

should do the trick.